# Running Hot-reload in Vagrant VM

Tags: vagrant, nuxt.js, hot-reload

I'm trying to develop a nuxt app on my Laravel Homestead Vagrant box since that's how (Nginx on Ubuntu) it will be served up live on the web, but there doesn't seem to be a way to watch files when it's being served on the vm.

If I run yarn dev on my Mac it will serve it up on localhost:3000 and hot reloading works as expected, but if I run yarn dev in the vm, it loads up on the vm localhost:3000 which is being listed to in nginx, it serves up the site under the domain as normal, but doesn't register any file changes.

Is there a way to run this so that file changes will get reflected in the vm and trigger the reload?

Answer (score 0):

```
vagrant rsync-auto
```

This will sync your shared folder without reloading the whole vm